# Data not getting updated in an array of object when changed value for one key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an array of certain records in a table, which are comprised of Date and Text fields, any input is given or changed will set data accordingly. My concern is that when Date input is changed Text value is undefined although we have data for it on table, whereas when Text input is changed Date value is undefined. My intention is that I need to show all data associated to it with that respective id. Please go through the code below:

```
const handleChange = (data) => {
    const { id: newId, textVal: franchise, dateVal: dateData } = data;
    setDataNew((prevInfo) => {
      const newList = [...prevInfo];
      const index = newList.findIndex((datum) => datum.newId === newId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        if (newId !== undefined) {
          newList[index].newId = newId;
        }
        if (franchise !== undefined) {
          newList[index].franchise = franchise;
        }
        if (dateData !== undefined) {
          newList[index].dateData = dateData;
        }
      } else {
        newList.push({ newId, franchise, dateData });
      }
      return [...newList];
    });
  };
```

As you can see from above code, we have data shown only on onChange. How can we show both object data when any either of data is changed.

[image]

Please refer to the image as well, when any data changed for date text is undefined and vice-versa for other.

Please also refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-frost-htyzhm?file=/src/Table.js

Answer (score 0):

In the codesandbox I see that `dataNew` it's initialized as an empty array, so when you call `setDataNew()` it creates a new object that has only the properties you're setting in the update function.
You need to initialize `dataNew` with the data that you are using on the table.

Comment: If possible can you please update the sandbox

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through your code an i noticed that you are missing to pass those values in your callbacks.

So extend you callbacks in your Grid.js like this:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    textCallback({
        textVal: e.target.value,
        id: rowData[0].id,
        dateVal: rowData[4]
    });
}}
```

and

```
onChange={(e) => {
    dateCallback({
        textVal: e.target.value,
        id: rowData[0].id,
        dateVal: rowData[3]
    });
}}
```

Comment: Hello... can you update the sandbox?

Comment: On text change value...it only works for first time but, when date is changed it takes previous value for text

Comment: You are never updating your GridData in the Table.js file. Thats why it "resets" every time you try to change the Text or Date. Update your GridData in the handleChange function.

Comment: Yes I tried... but, no solution